# Extracting the lines that match with another column of other file

Tags: python

I've 2 files tab delimited with a lot of columns (.tsv format). 
I've made a python script that gives you the complete lines of one file if a certain value of one column differ with the other file:

```
File A:
ID   Name1   Name2   Name3   NameN

File B:
ID   Name1   Name2   Name3   NameN
```

```py
normal=open('File1.tsv','r')
tumor=open('File2.tsv','r')

a=normal.readlines()
b=tumor.readlines()

A=[]
for ln in a:
    A.append(ln.split('\t')[9])
B=[]
for ln in b:
    B.append(ln.split('\t')[9])

normal.close()
tumor.close()

c=[]

for k, i in enumerate(B):
    if i not in A:
        c.append(b[k])      

co=open('c.txt','w')
for ln in c:
    co.write(ln)
```

Now what I'm trying to do is the oposite. I mean, if I find a coincidence, the output should be the full lines of file2.

I thougt changing only the last conditional of the code will fix, but it doesn't.

Any idea? thanks!

Comment: To be sure, in your first case do you want to compare the value in a line of tumor  with the same line in the normal? Or from your `for k, i in enumerate(B):` it looks like you are simply checking if that tumor line doesn't exist anywhere in normal file. Please clarify.
Also please confirm if `c.append(b[k])` is a typo. It should be `c.append(B[k])`

Comment: @perennial_noob `c.append(b[k])` is not a typo because `b` contains the full lines, while `B` contains just the 9th column of each row, and the OP wants to output the full lines.

Comment: @perennial_noob, the first case my script works because I get the unique lines of tumor, but the OP as blhsing suggested is not working

Comment: So I go back to my other question. Do you want a line to be appended if the corresponding columns of the line in normal and tumor are equal/match? If so you need to change it to equality check instead of `if i in A:`

Comment: That is what I want @perennial_noob, but with this conditional is not working
`for k, i in enumerate(B):
 if i in A:
  c.append(b[k])`

Comment: Maybe it will be useful to post a small subset of the data and the output you are getting. If these are string values then there maybe whitespace characters that are causing unintended consequences; just a possibility.

Comment: Btw, if you want the full lines of normal file if even one line in tumor matches normal line, then in the if condition, just break and take the whole A (normal file) as is. That's what you want, right?

Comment: Almost, what I want is the full lines of tumor file if there is a match. But I do not what to do now T_T

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do the opposite, to output only rows in the second file where the values of the 10th column are the same in both files, then changing:

```
if i not in A:
```

to:

```
if i in A:
```

should do.

Comment: But apparently that is not working, according to OP. I feel the question lacks clarity on that.

Comment: The OP did not show us how he changes the last condition so it's rather likely that the OP changed it in an incorrect way.

Comment: Exactly, it is what I did. But the output that I get is weird because I have some matches and some others lines that is unique for B.